# Creating an instance using a constructor with both bean and non-managed bean parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, javabeans

A Non-managed bean instance containing references to both other non-managed beans can be made aware of managed spring beans by using `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#autowireBean(instance)` which will inject all managed spring beans annotated with `@Autowired` annotation and this works great with `@Autowired` fields and/or methods.

Spring now suggests using constructor injection which brings me to the question: Is there a way to create an instance of a non-managed bean using a constructor so that all managed beans are injected, along with custom non-managed parameters?

Something along the lines of `AutowireCapableBeanFactory#newInstance(Class, Object... nonManagedParameters)` which would (in my mind at least) attempt to instantiate an instance of a given class by supplying it with spring managed beans where applicable, and use `nonManagedParameters` for the rest.

Does something like that exist?

Comment: Why not simply instantiating the class (within an `@Bean` annotated method)?

Comment: @fateddy because sometimes instances need to be instantiated dynamically (for example, after  reading some data from database) and then `@Bean` is not applicable